# Localizar números de telefones dentro de um arquivo txt

Tags: c#

Como posso listar arquivos **.txt** que contenha números de **telefones** nesse formato **(99)99999-9999 celular** e **(99)9999-9999 fixo** ?

Esse é o código que fiz até agora, só falta encontrar dentro do arquivo .txt a string no formato de um telefone:

```
private static void ListarArquivos()
        {
            try
            {

                string[] _diretorios = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\Arquivos\");
                Console.WriteLine("LSITA DE DIRETÓRIOS: ");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                foreach (string dir in _diretorios)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dir);

                    string[] arrArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt");

                    for (int x=0; x < arrArquivos.Length; x++)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(arrArquivos[x]))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(arrArquivos[x]))
                            {
                                string linha;
                                while ((linha = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {

                                    Console.WriteLine(linha);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" O arquivo " + arrArquivos[x] + "não foi localizado !");
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Exemplo de arquivo txt, quero que **NÃO** liste o **arquivo2.txt** por que não tem numero de telefone:

**Exemplo do arquivo1.txt:**
55(11)97387-0245
ORGANIZAÇÕES LTDA
55(11)99678-3199
55(11)97100-0445
MARIA JOSÉ DA SILVA

**Exemplo do arquivo2.txt**:
JOÃO DA SILVA
ORGANIZAÇÕES LTDA
PADARIA ESTRELA
QUITANDA 2 IRMÃOS
MARIA JOSÉ DA SILVA

**Exemplo do arquivo3.txt**:
(11)5489-9873
ORGANIZAÇÕES LTDA
PADARA ESTRELA
(11)5489-5912
MARIA JOSÉ DA SILVA

Comment: terias algumas linhas do seu arquivo para mostrar?

Comment: @Tiedt Tech editei o post e inseri exemplo dos arquivos txt

Comment: funcionou a minha resposta?

Comment: Bom dia @Tiedt Tech funcionou sim. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar você pode usar `Regex`.
Fiz um exemplo simples em

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VAsL7a.

#### Testando `Regex` Online

http://regexstorm.net/tester

Em Pattern coloque:

```
\(..\)[0-9]{3,5}-[0-9]{4}
```

Em Input coloque:

```
55(11)97387-0245
55(11)7387-0245
ORGANIZAÇÕES LTDA
55(11)99678-3199
55(11)97100-0445
MARIA JOSÉ DA SILVA
```

**Resultado**

4 matches

#### Links sobre `Regex`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx

http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/seja-ninja.html

**Documentação mais forte em Português sobre `Regex`**

http://piazinho.com.br/

Abaixo o seu código ajustado.

```
private static void ListarArquivos()
{
    try
    {
        string[] _diretorios = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\Arquivos\");
        Console.WriteLine("LSITA DE DIRETÓRIOS: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Regex rgx = new Regex("\\(..\\)[0-9]{3,5}-[0-9]{4}");

        foreach (string dir in _diretorios)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dir);

            string[] arrArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt");

            for (int x=0; x < arrArquivos.Length; x++)
            {
                if (File.Exists(arrArquivos[x]))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(arrArquivos[x]))
                    {                       
                        var total = rgx.Matches(sr.ToString()).Count;
                        if (total > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Tem telefones");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" O arquivo " + arrArquivos[x] + "não foi localizado !");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

acho que serve:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\([(\d))]{2}\)\s?[(\d)]{4,5}+\-+[(\d)]{4})");
    // formatos válidos 
    //(00)0000-0000 
    //(00)90000-0000
    //(00) 0000-0000
    //(00) 90000-0000
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"arquivo.txt"))
    {
        string linha;
        while ((linha = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // testa cada linha
            Match match = regex.Match(linha);
            if (match.Success)
                {
                    // arquivo tem telefone.                       
                }
            else 
               {
                    // arquivo não tem telefone.                       
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[Regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

caso queria melhorar o `regex`:

https://regex101.com/r/7Bb73s/1

Comment: Obrigado! Muito util.